# Wrap axis labels in dc.js Bar Chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Is there a way to wrap the axis labels in dc.js.
I tried searching the internet where i could find solutions by using d3.js and it doesn't work using dc.js.
Appreciate your help in advance!!
Thanks

Comment: dc.js directly uses d3.axis, so if you find a solution that works for d3, it should work with dc.js. Keep in mind that for now dc.js is still using d3 version 3, so you may need to any solutions you find for d3v4. Text wrap is not something built into SVG, so in general it is going to take some code to do the width calculations. What solutions were you looking at? Please add more detail to your question.

Comment: Sorry couldn't attach my template because of restrictions. I have the longer fields like,  Windows Server 2008 R2, Mac OS 10.10.5, Windows Server 2012 R2. I have over 15 unique fields similar to this. Is there any way we can wrap the fields to 2 or 3 lines in the axis level?